# Boundary conditions for Lagrangian formulation of General Relavitiy

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, boundary-conditions, variational-principle

I am reading section 4.1.3. of Poisson's book "A relativist's toolkit" and I am a bit perplexed by condition (4.13), namely that the variational principle for General Relativity has to be subjected to the following Dirichlet boundary conditions
$$
\delta g_{\mu\nu}=0
$$on the boundary of spacetime. These conditions fix 10 metric components, whereas we know that 4 of them are just gauge.

In quite some papers (e.g. [arXiv:1805.11559](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11559)) I found that the correct Dirichlet boundary conditions are actually
$$
\delta h_{ab}=0
$$
where $h_{ab}$ is the induced metric on the boundary, while the gauge degrees of freedom have to satisfy a condition that follows from the gauge choice.

Obviously, neither set of boundary conditions is gauge invariant, but I understand better why one would impose the latter. Are the former boundary conditions actually ok from a mathematical point of view?

Comment: In which signature?

Comment: I did not consider this to be determinant as I don't know how it would change the answer to my question. I guess I would be interested in knowing the answer for both Euclidean and Lorentzian signature if that is the case